# Kotlin - How to recursively call a lambda function

Tags: recursion, lambda, kotlin

I'm trying to re implement the linrec function from [here](http://raganwald.com/2016/12/15/what-higher-order-functions-can-teach-us-about-libraries-and-frameworks.html) in Kotlin. Here is what it currently looks like in Kotlin:

```
fun <A, B> linrec(indivisible: (List<A>) -> Boolean,
                  value: (List<A>) -> B,
                  divide: (List<A>) -> List<List<A>>,
                  combine: (A, B) -> B
                  ) : (List<A>) -> B {
  val myfunc: (List<A>) -> B = { input ->
    if (indivisible(input)) {
      value(input)           
    } else {
      val split = divide(input)
      val left = split[0][0]
      val right = myfunc(split[1])  // Error
      combine(left, right)   
    }
  }
  return myfunc
}
```

IntelliJ gives me the following errors, when I try to run the code:

```
Error:(40, 19) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: myfunc
```

My question is: **How do I make a lambda function call itself?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't call a lambda ("anonymous function") from inside itself. That's what functions are for:

```
fun <A, B> linrec(indivisible: (List<A>) -> Boolean,
                  value: (List<A>) -> B,
                  divide: (List<A>) -> List<List<A>>,
                  combine: (A, B) -> B
                  ) : (List<A>) -> B {

  fun myfunc(input: List<A>): B {     // rearranged things here
    return if (indivisible(input)) {  // added `return`
      value(input)           
    } else {
      val split = divide(input)
      val left = split[0][0]
      val right = myfunc(split[1])
      combine(left, right)            // *   
    }
  }
  return ::myfunc
}
```

Now this is exactly the code you've wrote, but it does not compile. On the line I marked with `*` kotlinc says `Type mismatch: inferred type is B but A was expected`.

P.S. I have no idea what that code is doing, so I only fixed  the compilation error you've asked about.

Comment: Thanks, that works. The signatur of combine should be (A, B) -> B. fixed that in the question.

Comment: If you're interested in actually creating a recursive lambda, you can look into the concept of y-combinators. I found this page with a list of implementations of it in different languages (no Kotlin yet though): https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator